# Move a file from a location to another in UNIX

Tags: c, linux, shell, unix

I have to implement a shell in unix with some commands

I want to move multiple files into a folder location like mv -t does.

The problem is that rename function, just rename a file dont move that file.

```
void mv_t()
{
  int mutat;
  char mvFile_name1[256];
  char mvFile_name2[256];
  int nr=0;

  printf("How many files you want to move: ");
  fflush(stdin);
  scanf("%d", &nr);

  printf("The file where you move: ");
  fflush(stdin);
  scanf("%s", &mvFile_name1);

  for(i=0; i<nr; i++)
  {
    printf("The file you want to move: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%s", &mvFile_name2);

    mutat = rename(mvFile_name1, mvFile_name2);
    if(mutat != 0)
      perror("Error");
  }
}
```

This is what I wrote. 
In "for" he take mvFile_name1 and rename it as mvFile_name2, and then he don't have the previous name for the file. But if this will work, still don't move the files in the mvFile_name1, he just rename them like mvFile_name1.

Comment: This `fflush(stdin);` is *undefined behavior*, it works on windows for non important reasons, but on unix it's simply *undefined behavior*. This is wrong too `scanf("%s", &mvFile_name1);`. What is the difference between *move* and *rename*? You want to move them phisically?

Comment: @iharob It works on many Unices, too. Doesn't mean that you should use it.

Comment: Do you specify a full destination path in mvFile_name2 (something like "/path/to/new/file")?

Comment: The C standard is very clear about `fflush`ing an input stream: http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.5.2p2 . No need to care why/if it might work sometimes.

Comment: There is no *move* in Unix, only renaming, because file are not what you think: files are in a flat space and their names are just strings (roughly) that refers to them and stored into directory contents. So *moving* is just a renaming, changing the name or changing the place of the name (but the file doesn't move).

Answer (score 3):

You have your args to `rename()` in the wrong order, swap them.

They are:

```
rename(oldpath, newpath);
```

Also you need to construct the newpath by striping off any path
(part before a /) in the mvFile_name2 and replacing that with
mvFile_name1.

Also you should verify that mvFile_name1 is a directory.

So if the person enters:

```
1
/tmp
/some/place/this.txt
```

then you should do:

```
rename(/some/place/this.txt, /tmp/this.txt);
```

Also if the oldpath and the newpath are on different disks, this will fail, but that may be more complication than you want to deal with.

Also, everything that @iharob said.

Comment: Since this is a beginner problem, for anything other than the homework assignment at hand, calling `system( "mv...")` is probably the quickest/easiest solution for the problem of moving across disks.  I'm guessing since he's writing a shell, that's not allowed though.   Other possibly reasonable options are your own `fread`/`fwrite` loop or `sendfile` (Linux-only).

Comment: I concur with your assessment.

Answer (score 2):

Even if your code worked, it has some problems

1. The `fflush()` function's behavior is not defined for *input* streams in the c standard, only for output. Thus, `fflush(stdin)` is undefined behavior.
2. You must check `scanf()`'s return value, not doing so might cause problems specially for the `"%d"` specifier.
3. This `scanf("%s", &mvFile_name1);` is wrong because `mvFile_name1` is already a pointer to the first element of the array. Passing it's address is wrong because the resulting pointer has the wrong type.